# Locally save a dataframe from a remote server in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pytorch, remote-server

I'm running a python script in VSCode on a remote server and I want to save a dataframe that is generated in that script locally. Is this somehow possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the dataframe to a directory (maybe in `.csv`) on the remote server and download it from the explorer in VSCode by right-clicking on that file.